# Curls and Gradients

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, vectors

I came across a question asking me to find the curl of a vector field and explain why it is not the gradient of any function. Why is that the case? Does it have to do with the fact that curl pinpoints the center of rotation of a body/fluid? In that case then, it would be perpendicular to the motion of a body/fluid and in that way, not capable of indicating the rate of change of motion?

I'm extremely confused and would appreciate any help.

Comment: The curl of $F$ is $0$ if $F$ is the gradient of a twice differentiable function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that concept? I didn't understand.

Comment: A vector field with nonzero curl is not conservative, while the gradient of a scalar field is always conservative. You can prove curl(grad f) = 0 as an identity from the definitions. I am looking for a good explanation online. [This link seems good (pdf)](http://ccom.ucsd.edu/~ctiee/notes/grad_n_curl.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean "not conservative" ? turbulent fluid has non-zero curl almost everywhere ! beside, I don't see the relation with the question that is "there is no $\phi$ such that $\nabla\times v = \nabla\phi$".

Answer (score 1):

The claim is "there is no $\phi$ such that $\nabla\times v = \nabla\phi$". 
If you take the div of it, you get on the left $\nabla\cdot\nabla\times v$ which is 0, and on the right $\Delta\phi$. The solution depends on the boundary conditions for $phi$. If there are no boundaries, and we assume $\phi=0$ at infinity, then the only allowed (boring) solution is $\phi=0$ (for irrotational fluids).

The intuitive explanation is that far from boundaries, the vorticity forms loops filaments. And you can't get a closed loop be a gradient (which would mean parametrising the loop without jump).